# undefined reference to `hostGetByName' VxWorks

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, embedded, vxworks

I am trying to compile a simple vxworks RTP app. I am getting undefined reference to `hostGetByName'. This function should be available in user space according to the documentation, and ive included the necessary layer "IPNET_USRSPACE" in the VSB but still getting the error. Any ideas what im missing?

```
    /* includes */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <hostLib.h>
#include <sockLib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (
    int    argc,    /* number of arguments */
    char * argv[]   /* array of arguments */
    ) {
    
    
    
    char *inGroup;
    int host;
    
    host = hostGetByName(inGroup);

    return 0;
}
```

> undefined reference to `hostGetByName'

Comment: [gethostbyname`?](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html)

Comment: @user4581301: there is an actual hostGetByName in VxWorks - [see here](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~courses/ee8205/Data-Sheets/Tornado-VxWorks/vxworks/ref/hostLib.html#hostGetByName)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Groovy. Glad I held back on voting to close as a typo. Now that I think harder, that wouldn't have been a linker error. Prototype is similar to the old `gethostbyname`. Wonder if the name difference stems from fear of getting sued.

Comment: The first hit on Google tells me this is part of something called "hostLib". Are you perhaps not linking to that library?

Comment: did you include INCLUDE_HOST_TBL in the VIP?

Comment: @ieio Yes, its defined in prjComps.h

Comment: @Botje how do i link the library?  I have tried -lhostLib but vxworks cant find it. Dont think im using the correct name.

Comment: No clue, never used vxworks before. I was hoping you would have the sdk in front of you.

Comment: add libnet.a, you should find it in the VSB directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like linker is not picking net lib.

`-lnet` will do the work.

Comment: Thats right, apparently beginning with SR600 the new compiler(llvm) will not auto link the libnet.a, so you need to add the library manually.